# small white tracking box i cant get rid of

Tags: tracking

[image: small white tracking box]

new to blender and accidentally clicked SOMETHING, now i have this annoying box that's "tracking" and i cant get rid of it. ive searched through youtube and other sources for about an hour but since i dont know what feature it is i can find no useful info.  (also, may be unrelated but now grease pencil stopped working as well)

Comment: Simply press your `delete` key when he object is selected (white)

Answer (score 1):

This is a [tracking point](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/editors/movie_clip_editor/tracking/clip/marker.html#point) used for [motion tracking](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/editors/movie_clip_editor/tracking/index.html).

It is creating by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + the opposite for your select button. 
To get rid of it, simply select it and press <kbd>X</kbd>, delete.

Answer (score 0):

Just delete it with X or Del button.
Or learn motion tracking - it allows you to create something like this: https://youtu.be/dfe0HLVa9Go :)

Good tutorials:
https://youtu.be/5HvLTJ4Zgo0 (basic)
https://youtu.be/1v-Bf9XOXIg (advanced)